# Sync file on iCloud not working between devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, synchronization, icloud

I try to sync a simple text file by using iCloud. 
My idea is to save my local text file (localURL) to iCloud (for example with an iPhone device):

```
NSURL *ubiquityURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:localURL
                                        toURL:ubiquityURL
                                        error:&error]
```

Once the file has been saved successfully on iCloud, with another device (as an iPad) I try to find the cloud-saved text file, but no data is read.

```
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:ubiquityURL.path error:&error];
```

If I try to search the file with the same device (iPhone) the fileList Array lists my backup file correctly. 
The ubiquityURL has the same URL and PATH for both devices.

Could you please explain me where i'm wrong?